# recursion problems

Tags: php

I'm grabbing links from a website, but I'm having a problem in which the higher I set the recursion depth for the function the results become stranger

for example 
when I set the function to the following

```
crawl_page("http://www.mangastream.com/", 10);
```

I will get a results like this for about half the page

**http://mangastream.com/read/naruto/51619850/1/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2/read/naruto/51619850/2**

EDIT

while I'm expecting results like this instead

**http://mangastream.com/manga/read/naruto/51619850/1**

here's the function I've been using to get the results

```
function crawl_page($url, $depth)
{
    static $seen = array();
    if (isset($seen[$url]) || $depth === 0) {
        return;
    }
    $seen[$url] = true;

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $element) {
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
            $href = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
        }
         if(shouldScrape($href)==true)   
          crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
    }
    echo $url,"\r";
//,pageStatus($url)
}
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please take a look over here: http://bit.ly/euWl1P

Comment: Apart from that: what is the result you are expecting? What is the result you are looking for?

Comment: @dbomb101: sorry bout that. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursive_humor

Comment: I'm expecting to get a listing of all of the links on the on a website

Comment: I mean I'm just expecting a list of links, eventually I'm going to use it to get all the links off a site, also very nice >_<

Comment: I doubt it would kill you if you actually listed what you expect in the question. Not describe it in a meta-sense. just actually show it. And tell why you think you should get this, or what the problem is. Now I'm going to have to go to that site and check out the source for you.....

Comment: I've added one of the results which I was actually expecting, if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the construction of your new url is not correct, replace :

```
$href = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
```

with :

```
if (substr($href, 0, 1)=='/') {
  // href relative to root
  $info = parse_url($url);
  $href = $info['scheme'].'//'.$info['host'].$href;
} else {
  // href relative to current path
  $href = rtrim(dirname($url), '/') . '/' . $href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in this line:

```
$href = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
```

To all relative urls on any given page this statement will prepend the current page url, which is obviously not what you want. What you need is to prepend only the protocol and host part of the URL.

Something like this should fix your problem (untested):

```
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$href = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host '] . $href;
```